# .NET Can't diagnose USER object leak

Tags: .net, memory-leaks

I have a WinForms application which is quite large but I have detected a USER object leak (and a smaller GDI leak) using Task Manager.

Once the app is running I open a form which displays some data retrieved from the server component (using WCF). I then close the form. For the purposes of testing I am then running garbage collection.

I then take a base note through Task Manager of USER and GDI counts and repeat open / close / collect a number of times.

During this process I see the following:
USER / GDI counts

824 / 347

830 / 349

835 / 349

867 / 361

872 / 361

876 / 361

908 / 371

940 / 381

945 / 381

977 / 391

Now considering I am consistently performing the same operations I cannot understand why the USER / GDI increase is non-linear. If everything is being disposed properly it should really be zero, or mostly zero.

I have tried using JetBrains DotMemory using snapshots before and after an operation and I have for example found that between 2 snapshots there might only be 4 objects that were not there at the beginning of the iteration - all four being instances of the undocumented System.Windows.Forms.Command. And yet the USER object count has increased!

This suggests to me that something in the code is not properly disposing / releasing some of these unmanaged USER objects. It's clearly not managed objects that are the problem (apart from the 4 spurious Command objects and I've no idea what they do).

My code does not use any unmanaged resources - It is calling Microsoft classes and Infragistics classes. Now I know that Infragistics has a reputation for being leaky but normally that is to do with static binding objects and that, according to DotMemory is not happening here (already taken care of removing use of those). I would also expect a repeated operation to show a linear leak.

So my question really is: how do I find out what USER and GDI objects are in use? Memory profilers don't seem to cover this. I've tried UISpy for USER objects but that seems next to useless in this instance. It shows all those that I'd expect to be in use, but none of the extra ones.

I'm more concerned about the USER objects as they grow faster and are more likely to smash the 10,000 limit between app restarts but the spurious GDI increase does interest me too of course.

I don't object to a little leak here and there because it probably isn't going to cause an impact and I'd rather development time was spent productively and not diagnosing little leaks that may be in 3rd party components anyway and so hard to get fixed.

Comment: Fix c# vb.net tags as I don't see any code in those languages and run 10000x for real test not 10x

Comment: Did you run Visual Studios static code analysis and did you fix all "Not disposed properly" messages?

Comment: Form.Command is a lead of sorts, you should look for the olden .NET 1.0 Menu, ContextMenu and MenuItem classes in your code.  They use the legacy built-in support for menus in Windows, that will get the USER Object counter to tick up.  And GDI Objects if you hacked the MenuItem to display an icon or bitmap.  Such a hack is in itself a good way to leak.  Otherwise, USER object leaks are a standard signal for broken Controls.Clear or Controls.Remove/At code.  Such code must dispose the removed controls, it often doesn't.

Comment: @nvoigt - Static code analysis found a few undisposed drawing objects elsewhere. But nothing in this area.

Comment: @cladius - Sorry, my bad on the tags. Corrected

Comment: @HansPassant - this app was upgraded from .NET1.1 to .NET3.5 and there are so many menus to change that we kept the old ones (eventually the client will be replaced by a browser based version). especially as the upgrade was really non-trivial. Are you saying that the old menus are leaky? This has big implications if so. I can put up with USER count changing, but not constantly growing. Trying to reproduce in a small test app

Comment: @HansPassant - I have created a small app which does everything the normal app does in terms of creating new forms using mainmenu and contextmenu etc. There is no need for explicit dispose as everything is auto-disposed by the form (as it should be). USER count goes up and down as you'd expect. If objects were not being disposed you'd see them on the memory profiler and I don't. I just see the USER count randomly increasing :o(

Answer (score 1):

It's taken a while to identify but after a lot of debugging and commenting code I  narrowed it down to Infragistics UltraTextEditor. If I set AlwaysInEditMode=True then I get this leak. If I set it to False then I don't. Similarly if I add just another UltraTextEditor to the user control (and do nothing with it) and set AlwaysInEditMode=True then I get the leak too.

I tired to reproduce this in a small test project but was unable to and continued investigating.

What I eventually found was a panel that was being removed deep in a user control (when a display section was effectively collapsed) which contained three instances of the Infragistics UltraTextEditor as well as some other Windows controls. Now it seems that the panel and controls were being garbage collected (no references) but they were not being Disposed. This did not seem to matter for the non-Infragistics controls (I guess they don't use unmanaged resources?) but the Infragistics control has one USER object that was not being cleaned up. The way the Infragistics UltraTextEditor works is a bit odd. It is comprised of two text boxes, one I think is the standard MS textbox and the other is an Infragistics developed textbox. In normal operation it displays one when the control has focus and the other one when it loses focus. By setting AlwaysInEditMode=True I think it must have at that point disposed of one of them (the one with the unmanaged resource). Consequently when this had not been set, when the control was eventually garbage collected without having been disposed it must have left the unmanaged resources unreleased.

So, developer error. But it's been a real slog. Memory profiling did not show the problem. And there is nothing that enables you to track down feral USER objects. If I'd been able to see what they represented it would have been a lot easier to identify a pattern and the whole problem. Plus using Infragistics somewhat obscured things because, being a black box, you don't really know, or need to know, what happens under the covers. Which is fine until it doesn't work!

I still don't have an answer for the non-linear nature but of course the framework is doing all sorts of things in the background, responding to mouse movements and enter/leave events. Need a decent USER object analyser!